# vtkOBJReader object has no attribute SetFileNameMTL (.mtl) for Object (.obj) files

Tags: python-3.x, vtk

The code below complains that vtk.vtkOBJReader() object has no method SetFileNameMTL().

In the documentation it appears to exist [vtkOBJImporter.SetFileNameMTL](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkOBJImporter.html#a983672176eed1b06b5b0702b7b7aa634) (*Maybe the python wrapper for this is missing?*).

How can the material (.mtl) for the object be set when parsing the (.obj) in vtk and made visible in k3d?

```
import k3d
import vtk
import ipywidgets as widgets

reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader() 
reader.SetFileName('sample_obj/Model.obj')
reader.SetFileNameMTL('sample_obj/Model.mtl') #Attribute not found
reader.Update() 

plot = k3d.plot()
poly_data = reader.GetOutput()

plot += k3d.vtk_poly_data(poly_data)
plot.display()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using vtkOBJReader, not vtkOBJImporter.  Those are two different classes.  vtkOBJReader is the older class, I think, and only reads in the geometry file.  To load the material info, you need to use vtkOBJImporter.

Comment: How would one pass the data to k3d with both the geometry and the texture information using the vtkOBJImporter class?

Comment: So the vtkOBJImporter appears to load an entire scene. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to get the mesh.  However I tried using vtkOBJReader to load the mesh, and then read an image myself in k3d to apply it as texture.  I followed the following k3d example, but the texture didn't show up.  The mesh did have UV coords, though.  https://github.com/K3D-tools/K3D-jupyter/blob/master/examples/textured_mesh.ipynb

Comment: Yes was looking at the same example, I managed to get some textures to show up in k3d correctly when I can predict the mesh uv mapping for glb files using vtkGLTFReader(). However failing to reproduce the same thing when dealing with obj/mtl.